# Claim permission value with context

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, claims-based-identity, claims

I'm starting to use claim-based authorization for my asp.net web API project.

In my projects users can have permission to edit entities. But user have permission to edit `entity1`, but not `entity2`. In formal, he should be able to do `POST entities/1`, but not `POST entities/2`.

I'm thinking, how to add this information in Claims. I see 2 approaches:

1. Add Claim with value containing id of entity:

   ```
   this.AddClaim(new Claim("permission", "entity/1/edit"));
   this.AddClaim(new Claim("permission", "entity/42/edit"));
   ```
2. Add Claim with type of `edit` and value is id of entity:

   ```
   this.AddClaim(new Claim("entity/edit", "1"));
   this.AddClaim(new Claim("entity/edit", "42"));
   ```

I admit that I miss something in concept of Claims. And, maybe there is a better way to achieve this.

Comment: so are trying to persist these claims somehow?

Comment: as to the format of creating a new claim i would go with : `.AddClaim(new Claim("claimType", "some important claim value"));`

Answer (score 1):

A better approach is the Resource-based authorization.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-2.2

If you are not in asp.net core You may try https://leastprivilege.com/2014/06/24/resourceaction-based-authorization-for-owin-and-mvc-and-web-api/

Basic Idea is you check access to the resource(the document). How this information is stored is not relevant when granting/denying access.

```
if (!HttpContext.CheckAccess(
    "Edit",
    "Album",
    id.ToString()))
{
    return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
}
```

You will then have a separate module where authorization rules are defined

```
app.UseResourceAuthorization(new ChinookAuthorization());
```

https://github.com/IdentityModel/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/blob/master/samples/OWIN/ResourceAuthorization/WebApp/ChinookAuthorization.cs

There you will check if the current user has access to this resource, Probably looking up the resource by resourceId in DB and check if the current user is allowed access.